# Django __str__ returned non-string (type DeferredAttribute)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am having a little problem with Django. When I try to access a particular view I get the error of the title *__ str__ returned non-string (type DeferredAttribute)*. I believe it has something to do with a form that I render in the view but I can't find the problem by myself.

Here is my model:

```
class ItemElements(models.Model):
   itemid = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   elementid = models.ForeignKey(Elements, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   percentage = models.IntegerField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The form:

```
class ItemElementsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = ItemElements
       fields = ['itemid', 'elementid', 'percentage']
       labels = {
           'itemid' : 'Item',
           'elementid' : 'Element',
           'percentage' : 'Percentage'
       }
```

The view:

```
def addelements(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ItemElementsForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           elementsForm= form.save(commit=False)
           elementsForm.save()
           return redirect('addelements')
   else:
       form = ItemElementsForm()
   return render(
       request,
       'add/addelements/index.html',
       {'form': form}
   )
```

I can't really see the problem. I copied and modified from another working form and view. Eveything else it's exactly the same as the other form that just works.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a MWE: a minimal example to reproduce the error. Right now you provide some parts where you *think* the problem occurs, but I personally can not see any problems with these.

Comment: Please fix indentation in the code under "The form". The `class Meta` definition should be indented into the form class.

Comment: @YoavGaudin In the original file is indented, is just a mistake while copy/pasting here.

Comment: The problem is the `__str__` method in the model, so you need to post that.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Since the code I posted is the only that differs from a working one, I don't really know what else should I add. I am not going to post over 10000 files of my django project.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I believe the error is in the form because on the terminal I get this File "C:\Projects\djangoproject\app\project\views.py", line 45, in addelements
    {'form': form}

Comment: @Adrian: yes, but a traceback does not per se shows the location of the *bug*: it shows where the bug started to cause problems.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know, but the rest of the code (the HTML file, urls.py) is just a copy of a working view of a different form on the same project. I just changed the names of the form, view and so on. The only thing that changes is the model and the form, even the view is a copy with just name changes of another view that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I found the problem. All I had to do was to create a primary key on the model.

```
primaryid = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your models. You should have something like

```
class ItemElements(models.Model):  
    itemid = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    elementid = models.ForeignKey(Elements, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    percentage = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self): #For Python 3, use __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.created_at)
```

Comment: Even after adding the __ str__ function I get exactly the same error.